# How to resize 3 divs relative to their parents (responsive)

Tags: css

How to resize 3 divs relative to their parents?
page-wrap is the main div.

Ok, here is the code in [codepen](https://codepen.io/b-artgrafik/pen/jkqAx)

```
#page-wrap { width: 960px; margin: 60px auto; }

#map_canvas { width: 100%; height: 400px; width: 300px; float: left; position: relative; z-index: 30 !important; }

#locations { list-style: none; width: 250px; float: left;  }

#more-info > div { background: #e9e2bf; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(70,49,1,0.5); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(70,49,1,0.5); padding: 20px; height: 320px; }
```

Comment: You probably want to use percentage widths (i.e., width = 33%) and if the padding is throwing you off, try using " box-sizing: border-box; ".  Not sure I fully understand your question though

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle with the issue, what you provided is not enough for understanding

Comment: You need to give a visual representation of your divs. Are they side by side? How were they supposed to look like? Elaborate further your question.

Comment: I don´t want the 3 divs to fall down when i resize them, i want them to stay side by side.

Here is the link: https://css-tricks.com/examples/GoogleMapSlider/
Files are here: https://css-tricks.com/google-maps-slider/

Comment: Here is the code in codepen https://codepen.io/b-artgrafik/pen/jkqAx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this will work

```css
#page-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

#map_canvas {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30 !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#locations {
  list-style: none;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#locations li {
  width: 100%;
}

#more-info {
  width: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#more-info>div {
  background: #e9e2bf;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(70, 49, 1, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(70, 49, 1, 0.5);
  padding: 20px;
  height: 320px;
}
```

Comment: It´s close.
When I resize the map gets too thin and the letters in #more-info come out of the boxes down.

Comment: In this example the text scales with the divs. https://codepen.io/cRckls/pen/mcGCL
I don´t know how to implement it tho.